# Render array value empty for Datetime field

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I'm using `hook_form_alter` to modify an admin edit node screen. The form has a datetime field which I'm unable to get the value for in the render array. textfields value usually appears in value->#default_value.

```
xxx_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  print(json_encode($form['field_date_test']['widget']));
}
```

[image]

When the page loads, the value is in the input field but I can't find where I can get hold of the value before the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was `$item['value']['#default_value']->render()`. This outputs the value in the following format `Y-m-d H:i:s e`.

Alternatively, calling `format('Y-m-d')` or any other format string will update accordingly

because '#default_value' was of type `DrupalDateTime` which must not implement `jsonSerialize` this is why I was getting and empty object for a value when dumping out as JSON.